# How do I include the users in the result set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pusher

```
comments = Song.find(65).comments.select('comments.*, users.*').includes(:user).limit(20)
```

How would I include the users in the result set?

Im using the [PusherApp](http://pusher.com/) and trying to do:

```
    Pusher["foo"].trigger("bar", { 
      :comments => comments
    })
```

Comment: Please, explain what you mean with include the users. If you select the comments including the users, they'll be loaded in `comment.user`

Comment: `comment.user` wont be accessible in the Pusher json object

Comment: `Song.find(65).comments.includes(:user).limit(20).map { |comment| {:comment => comment, :user => comment.user} }` something like this. But looking for a more efficient way of doing so

Comment: With `includes(:user)`, you're already loading all users using only 1 query more. Read the association documentation for Rails.

Comment: The result set SHOULD include users who have commented on the song, without me having to iterate through each comment object. Observe the example, I posted above

Comment: The result set already INCLUDES the users. From your example, you should access each comment with `result_set[index].comment` and each user with `result_set[idx].user`. But with includes you already have the comment in `result_set[idx]` and the user in `result_set[idx].user` without generating another `n` queries, just 1.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19211/discussion-between-serabe-and-christian-fazzini)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to generate json quite fast with custom fields, you better read [this tutorial](http://brainspec.com/blog/2012/09/28/lightning-json-in-rails/).

It basically uses a method like this:

```
def self.lightning
  connection.select_all(select([:latitude, :longitude, :timestamp, :virtual_odometer]).arel).each do |attrs|
    attrs.each_key do |attr|
      attrs[attr] = type_cast_attribute(attr, attrs)
    end
  end
end
```

This return an array of hashes.

Then uses `render json: Oj.dump(@statuses.lightning, mode: :compat)`, with the [oj gem](https://github.com/ohler55/oj).

Comment: Rails no longer uses `type_cast_attribute` - what would you do instead?

Answer (score 0):

replace includes(:user) with joins(:user) and you will be able to select user fields

```
comments = Song.find(65).comments.select('comments.*, users.*').joins(:user).limit(20)
```

Comment: Only returns the comments objects